# Get php file value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, get

We have 5 inputs (`type="text"`) on html page `/edit_person.php`:

```
<input id="name" name="name" value="" />
<input id="surname" name="surname" value="" />
<input id="age" name="age" value="" />
<input id="begin" name="begin" value="" />
<input id="end" name="end" value="" />
```

And a php file `/scripts/db.php`

If we open in browser `/scripts/db.php?get=1` it will give something like (an array with values):

```
$data = Array(
[name]=>Mark,
[surname]=>Twain,
[age]=>74,
[begin]=>November 30, 1835,
[end]=>April 21, 1910
)
```

**How can we request `/scripts/db.php?get=1` by ajax on `/edit_person.php` and insert received data to the inputs?**

jQuery last version is used and PHP 5.2.

If input currently has some value, it should be replaced.

**Output format of `db.php` can be changed, you can request options which would be better.**

Thanks.

Comment: That is a rather strange format what db.php outputs... `$data = Array(` is completely unnecessary, the line break is the data delimiter? Can you change it to... say, JSON?

Comment: @AndreKR, yes, output format can be changed. Linebreak is not good by the way some item inside array can be empty. Don't know how to use JSON. Or you mean to give a json format of an array by db.php? Please give some example.

Comment: Yes, convert strings to UTF-8, put them into an array, run json_encode on that array, echo it out and accept Pekka's answer. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`db.php` seems to be outputting the array in some custom, PHP-like format. I wouldn't do that. Use `json_encode()` instead: jQuery's Ajax can handle JSON data natively.

- [Docs on `jQuery.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) with examples
- If your JSON data is in a variable named `data`, the insertion into each input will be a simple `$("#name").val(data.name);`

Comment: I can change output type of db.php, so the ajax can handle it (which one would be better?). Trying to use this method, because of bad javascript knowledge.

Comment: @AndreKR true, true. Corrected

Comment: +1 Keep in mind that you need to feed strings in UTF-8 to json_encode, regardless of what charset your page uses.

Comment: so db.php should give data in format like {
    tags: "cat",
    tagmode: "any",
    format: "json"
  } ?

Comment: @Happy yes. jQuery's getJSON can then automatically parse it into a Javascript object

Comment: @Happy look at the jQuery manual link I posted, there are examples there